# Is there any to address the GPIO pins in Windows 11?

Tags: gpio, windows

I just got my Raspberry Pi 4 and want to run some servers. The server I want to run, runs exclusively on Windows, and not even Wine works. I also need Windows 11 for the improved x86 on ARM emulation. What I want to achieve is an automatic fan that only turns on when the CPU gets too hot.

I have not found any way yet to communicate with the pins on Windows 11. I did find Windows for IoT, but that's just Windows 10.

Is there any way to do this, or is my only option to leave the fan constantly running (directly from 5V)?

Comment: you are not thinking clearly ... the RPi runs Linux ... Windows runs in an emulator on Linux ... why should a virtual machine control the fan when Linux can control it

Comment: Are you saying you want to run Windows 11 on a Pi?  Is that possible?

Comment: The OP needs to run server software that "runs exclusively on Windows".  I'm sorry, Konsti219, but you should have done some rudimentary research before you bought the board.  Microsoft gave up on Pi support, but I believe there are other boards that it does -- you'll have to do some research *first* ;)

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for the info. The reason I got a Raspberry Pi was also cost. Guess I'll use it for something else. Maybe Wine will add some support at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Was a solution found?

I'm running windows 11 fine on the raspberry pi (On a SSD), but now would like to be able to access the GPIO pins via C / C++ / Python

I see there is a windows driver for the GPIOs